# Component to display model.parent in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I have template wich displays a model. In this template, I can see the model properties, even the child/parents ones.

I want to create a component to display the parent, but in the component I only got a 'promise'.

template:

```
...
{{expedient-header expedient=model.expedient}}
....
```

I pass the model.expedient (expedient has many documents, and document belongsTo expedient, in this case, model = document.

In the same template where I call the component, the model.expedient is a fetched record, but when I pass it to the component, it's only a Promise.

If I pass the model, I get the model, but I want to make this component more independent, and just pass the model.expedient.

Is this possible/supported?

As I'm just a 'newbie' with ember, I'm just playing, I could maybe refactor how I'm doing things but I would like to know if this is possible ...

:-)

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On init component you can work with promise, and after that render data.
Because component is it "controller" for view.

Comment: But I want to use only the .hbs part of the component, not the .js, as the data is there (in the template that is calling the component), maybe I'm missing some important thing here :-)

Comment: No, you need js too. Only on *.hbs you can't use promise... But you can use partical view or only child view